# How to apply theme to rectangle shape in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, themes, customization

Objective is to fill all rectangle or any generic shapes with a specified color via theme.json file
Docs: [PowerBI Themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes)

I have tried this but it does not affect the fill color of any rectangle. (I have also reverted all formatting to default for rectangles)

```json
...
"visualStyles": {
  "basicShape": {
    "*": {
       "fill": [{
          "show": true,
          "fillColor": {
            "solid": {
              "color": "#FFFFFF"
            }
          }
       }]
     }
  }
}
```